# Increment Bootstrap Progressbar on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have three buttons that when clicked I'd like to have incrementally increase the value of a progress bar.  Clicking one button equals a progress bar value of 33%, clicking two buttons 67%, three buttons 100%.  Essentially just like this: http://www.somawater.co/ksshare/

I've figured out how to have each button click set a value for the progress bar, but it resets on each click instead of adding incremental value.  Here's my code:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
<span class="sr-only">0% Complete (success)</span>
</div>
</div>

        <div class="main-action row">

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <button id="code1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Share</button>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <button id="code2" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Tweet</button>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <button id="code3" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Watch</button>
           </div>

        </div>
```

js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#code1').click(function () {
    var val = 33 + '%';
    $('.progress-bar').width(val).text(val)
})
});

jQuery(function ($) {
$('#code2').click(function () {
    var val = 34 + '%';
    $('.progress-bar').width(val).text(val)
})
});

jQuery(function ($) {
$('#code3').click(function () {
    var val = 33 + '%';
    $('.progress-bar').width(val).text(val)
})
});
```

The js on the http://www.somawater.co/ksshare/ page looks to be an elegant example but I can't figure out how to translate it into the Bootstrap framework:

```
$(function() {
var clicks = 0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
    clicks++;
    var percent = Math.min(Math.round(clicks / 3 * 100), 100);
    $('.percent').width(percent + '%');
    $('.number').text(percent + '%');
});
```

Finally, given my code, can someone help me implement the same 'sharing' js pop-ups when a button is clicked?  Thank you!

Comment: So, where are you stuck? You have the code there and it looks like it could be adapted quite easily by changing the selectors to fit your markup.

Comment: I don't know how to change the selectors to fit my markup.  This is the most advanced coding I've ever attempted.  Total noob here.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above example that you displayed is nearly there....but I would make one change the ('button')click event would trigger on any button you clicked so change it to be something like this:(either give it  class (button that is)...

```
$(function() {
var clicks = 0;
 $('.code-button').on('click', function() {
  clicks++;
  var percent = Math.min(Math.round(clicks / 3 * 100), 100);
  $('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').text(percent + '%');
 });
});
```

See how that goes. You probably would want to get a little more funky and disable the button after it was clicked...but if you are new to this then it might just cloud things a little!

Comment: Thank you!  That worked like a charm.  I added the 4th line so that each button can only advance the bar one time:

    `jQuery(function ($) {
    var clicks = 0;
    $( "#code1, #code2, #code3" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
      $( this ).off( event );
      clicks++;
      var percent = Math.round(clicks / 3 * 100);
      $('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').text(percent + '%');
    });
    
    });`